# Coturn Installation failed in Centos7

Tags: centos7, coturn

I followed this link https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html#centos to install turn server in centos 7. The Configuration step I gave user name and password , also gave the same port as per the guidelines.

And finally I run the comment:
"turnserver -v -r  127.1.1:2222 -a -b turnuserdb.conf -c turnserver.conf -u turn-username -r 127.1.1:2222 -p turn-password"

it showed Wrong user name in the execution.

Any idea for Coturn installation in Centos7 because i am new in webrtc...

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this instruction: https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/coturn-4.5.1.2-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

```
wget https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-12.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh epel-release-7-12.noarch.rpm
yum install coturn
```

Comment: Use the version 7-14 instead of 7-12.